# "Bad value for Range" - Can't Solve

Tags: ruby, rspec

So the point of this code is to translate pig latin (and apparently "u" doesn't count as a vowel).. this was for a exercise. I tried changing the 'for' loops values a load, then tried different 'if/else' statements. I'm rspec'ing the function with the important piece being

```
describe "#translate" do
  it "translates many words" do
    s = translate("the quick brown fox")
    expect(s).to eq("ethay ickquay ownbray oxfay")
  end
end
```

and I'm sorry I almost forgot to mention how the error even pops up. If the top paragraph doesn't make sense... my bad, forgot to mention the code that's problematic  is past

> '#'Method for inputs with spaces

and the error message that comes up for that rspec is

```
2) #translate translates many words
     Failure/Error: s = translate("the quick brown fox")
     ArgumentError:
       bad value for range
     # ./pig_latin.rb:25:in `translate'
     # ./pig_latin_spec.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm new at this and haven't read many questions (mostly just look at solutions) so sorry my point comes across kind of blurry

```
#write your code here
def translate input
    vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o"]
    output = input.split("")
    if (output.include?(" ") == false)
    i = 0
    #Method for inputs with no spaces
    while (i == 0) 
      #First Letter is not a vowel
      if ((vowels.include?(output[i])) == false)
          output.insert((output.length - 1), output.delete_at(i))

      else
         #Is a vowel
          output = output.join + "ay"
          i += 1
          break
      end
    end


  #Method for inputs with spaces
  else
      output = output.join.split
      for i in i..(output.length - 1)
      output[i] = output[i].split("")
        for x in x..10
          if ((vowels.include?(output[i][x])) == false)
            output[i].insert((output[i].length - 1), output[i].delete_at(x))
          else
            output[i] = output[i].join + "ay"
            i += 1
            break
          end
        end
      end
    output = output.join(" ")
    end 
    return output
end
```

Comment: Sorry, but did you actually read the error message? *"Bad value for range ... pig_latin.rb:25"*. On line 25 you define a range: `i..(output.length - 1)`, but **`i` is nil**. I'm *guessing* you meant to write `0..(output.length - 1)`... However, the code directly below (`for x in x..10` makes even less sense. Why you have split the method in two: "input with spaces" and "input without spaces"? Rather than trying to "fix" this second half of the if statement, just generalise the first half to work for an arbitrary number of words.

Comment: You should play around with your own solution, as a learning experience, but [here](https://repl.it/Da4g/0) is an example of what I'm talking about -- you've over-complicated things a lot here!

Comment: @TomLord oops... Yeah. But thanks!